# What does `take` mean in Ember.js template

Tags: ember.js

I've got this `each` loop in an ember template. What does the `take` argument do here?

```
{{#each (take 4 model.products) as |p|}}

{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is an helper from [ember-composable-helpers](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-composable-helpers#take). From their Github:

> Returns the first n entries of a given array.
>
> ```
> <h3>Top 3:</h3>
> {{#each (take 3 contestants) as |contestant|}}
>  {{contestant.rank}}. {{contestant.name}}
> {{/each}}
> ```

Comment: I do have that package installed! Thank you